# How to cast a nullable date time to a date time only if it has non null value

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I have these two lines of code:

```
result.birthdateSpecified = (someData.BirthDate != null || false);
result.birthdate = someData.BirthDate as DateTime;
```

I'd like to be able to set the result.birthdate to the someDate.BirthDate, only if it exists, in a single line.
So that I don't have to write any if statement. Just wondering if it's possible?

FYI - result.birthDate is a DateTime and someData.BirthDate is a DateTime? (nullable)

I know I can't cast it with 'as' but not sure if there is something else I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the other answers you can edit the first line as well to use the `HasValue` property of `Nullable` types:

```
result.birthdateSpecified = someData.BirthDate.HasValue;
result.birthdate = someData.BirthDate ?? default(DateTime);
```

Answer (score 4):

what about the null coalescing operator?

```
result.birthdate = someData.BirthDate ?? result.birthdate;
```

sure, the assignment will be done unconditionally, so the setter will be called, and the getter might be called... which might be a thing you don't want ... but the value will only change if someData.BirthDate is not null

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
result.birthdate = someData.BirthDate ?? default(DateTime);
```

Or you could replace `default(DateTime)` with whatever sentinel value you're using when `birthdateSpecified` is `false`.

I think it makes more sense from a client POV to ensure that when `birthdateSpecified` is false, there is a predictable "dummy" value in the `birthdate` field, rather than potentially leaving correct-looking data there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a combination of a null coalesce and self assignment:

```
result.birthdate = someData.BirthDate ?? result.birthdate;
```